# How do you replace htmlspecialchars simply?

Tags: java, android, replace

`input.replace("&amp;", "&").replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">").replace("&quot;", "\"");`

im using this line of code as a sudo htmlspecialchars converter. with my application, it doesnt need to be too elaborate.

for some reason the above code does not replace("&", "&"), it doesnt seem to do anything.

any advice?

`input = input.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7e]", "");`

i also tried this.

Comment: Tried URLDecoder.decode(THE STRING TO DECODE); ?

Comment: `&amp;lt;`? Oops. You really want to get this sort of thing *exactly* right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In android there is one class Html inside android.text.Html which you can use like this as below:

```
Html.fromHtml(any_html_text);
```

But this function will return Spanned object so use

```
Spanned spn=Html.fromHtml(any_html_text);
```

You can set this spanned text to any button or textview text Hope it will help you.

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) also for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this manually, check out the [Html class.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)  Calling `Html.fromHtml()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to escape/unescape html by replacing strings yourself you might introduce security issues in your application (depending on what it does with the output). Either use Html.FromHtml or from Apache libs org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml

Comment: I would highly recommend using the apache commons library. I have done so in the past and it is a much more complete and problem free solution

Answer (score 0):

This does the work -

```
 public String cleanString(String dirty) {

     return Html.fromHtml(dirty).toString();

    }
```